# Make external images fit in container

Tags: css, woocommerce

I am working on a woocommerce affiliate store.(https://salespotters.nl/shop) I import products with the plugin Datafeedr and I use the plugin 'external images' to display external images instead of importing them. The images are hosted on the website from the affiliate website.

Now my products images don't fit in the productcontainer anymore. (See screenshot) I used to generate thumbnails when I was still importing the images. Since the images are external urls now I can't edit them. I just started and still learning css but is there a way to make all the images fit in the same size container?

(Picture is screenshot made on phone but its the same on pc)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuHoV.jpg)

It worked with this code, sorry for the inconvience!:

```
#main .eiportrait{
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: How is this a "php" question?

Comment: Hi. Since this is a woocommerce site, please provide the link to the site so that we know what we can work on. Or, if you could, please also provide a minimal, reproducible code. Thanks :)

Comment: Please refer to the how to ask a good question guide:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You should edit your question to be more precise for example with adding code examples.

Comment: @denisey The url is in the text salespotters.nl/shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.image-div {
object-fit: contain;
}
```

Comment: It worked with #main .eiportrait{
 object-fit: contain;
}    Thanks alot!!